# fill one dimensional dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba

I have code like this.

```
Dim sums() As Single
dim n as integer
For n = 0 To ActiveCell.Value - 2
    sums(n) = Abs(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(i + m, 6), Cells(j - 1, 6)), Range("F" & i + m).Value, Range(Cells(i + m, 17), Cells(j - 1, 17))))
Next n
```

I am getting an error message for `sums(n)= ....` I would like to fill array with values according to formula. E.G I have in activecell value 3, then I would like to have array with 2 values like `sums(0) = abs(sumif..) and sums(1)= abs(sumif..)`.

I tried to calculate the formula without an array as sum1 = formula and it worked, but as soon as I changed it to the array because sometimes I will have there 2, 3 an more values in it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below changes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sums_()

Dim sums() As Single
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'assign the values or range of values for i,m,j


ReDim sums((ActiveCell.Value - 2) + 1)

For n = 0 To ActiveCell.Value - 2
sums(n) = Abs(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(i + m, 6), Cells(j - 1, 6)), Range("F" & i + m).Value, Range(Cells(i + m, 17), Cells(j - 1, 17))))
Next n


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to size your array first. Use `Redim` to do so before your loop:

```
Redim sums(0 to ActiveCell.Value - 2)
For n = 0 To ActiveCell.Value - 2
...
```

You can use `Redim` multiple times in your code, but note that if you want to keep the content of the array, you have to use `Redim preserve` and that is rather slow because the complete array is rebuild. So you should avoid to use `Redim preserve` within a loop.

Comment: Can you then accept the answer so that someone else with a similar question can see that the answer is okay